# How to use <If> <ElseIf> <Else> in Apache with custom variables?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, server, configuration, config

```
Define FOO "/bar/foo/bar_v1.0.0"

<If "${FOO} == '/bar/foo/bar_v1.0.0'">
    Define BAR2 "foofoo1"
</If>
<ElseIf "${FOO} == '/bar/foo/bar_v2.0.0'">
    Define BAR2 "foofoo2"
</ElseIf>
<Else>
    Define BAR2 "foofoo3"
</Else>
```

What I do wrong? I've read the [Apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/expr.html) and [this one too](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#elseif), but I can't see the problem.

• I've tried `'${FOO}'`, `${FOO}`, `'%{FOO}'`, `%{FOO}`.

• I've tried to remove quotes from the string: `<If "${FOO} == /bar/foo/bar_v1.0.0">`

• I've tried to remove double quotes at all: `<If ${FOO} == '/bar/foo/bar_v1.0.0'>`

• I've also tried `<If "${FOO} =~ /bar_v1\.0\.0/">` and

• `<If "${FOO} -strmatch '/bar/foo/bar.v1.0.0'">`

• I've also tried quote marks removed from the values that are set with the Define directive:

`Define FOO /bar/foo/bar_v1.0.0`

• I've tried to remove `ElseIf` block, and use just `If` and `Else`

And I always get BAR2 defined as a "foofoo3", cuz it just an exception (default) value I put in "else", just in case. So first two block never work no matter what.

I don't get it, can I even use custom variables in Apache expressions? The code is located in Apache config file.

---

I'm getting Apache error and it doesn't start. The error is because I use `BAR2` as a part of a path to load module. Of course Apache says it cannot load module, because actually I do not have such path `"/usr/foofoo3/some_module"` but I certainly have `"/usr/foofoo1/some_module"` and `"/usr/foofoo2/some_module"`, but as I said first 2 blocks never work

Comment: Where is this code located to begin with? I am wondering, because you tagged this `.htaccess` among other things, but in there it would of course not make any sense here to begin with - loading of your module can only happen in the server config or virtual host, so anything only happening in .htaccess would of course be way too late.

Comment: Yeah @CBroe you're right, loading module can only be done in config, but I guess I still can use `conditional expressions <If> <ElseIf> <Else>` inside .htaccess for other things, can't I?

Comment: Of course you can use them for other things. But if your loading of the module depends on a variable `BAR2`, then that variable must be set at this point already.

Comment: ? @CBroe what are U trying to say, that I shouldn't use .htaccess tag? I did that to grab more attention to my question, and I believe this tag is absolutely relative to the Apache expressions. I ask this question yesterday too, and had just 9 views and 0 answers, it's like only me is using this Apache feature... If you have something to say about my matter, then say it. I just really don't get why it isn't work.

Comment: I am saying, you should _clarify_ what I asked you right away - where is this code actually located?

Comment: I've updated my question @CBroe : The code is located in Apache config file.

Comment: What happens when you define `BAR2` directly there, outside of any conditions - does loading your module "dynamically" using a path that uses this variable work then?

Comment: If I define BAR2 outside the `If`, `ElseIf` block  or just change "foofoo3" inside `else` block to "foofoo1", everything okay, Apache starts, modules loaded, server works as usual, no errors. So, I'm saying, that conditional expression actually works, because `else` works, I just can get why top condition doesn't work as it should. @CBroe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yesterday I also tried to do same tests with Numbers instead of String and had the same result. So, I was confused, disappointed and actually done with it. I've just figured out another way, it's not so beautiful in my view, but I work with what I have. If someone interested here's the code, it gives me exactly what I need:
*(there's no "foofoo3" at all, as I said it was an exception, it was for testing, and I tested this code with BAR2 value as "foofoo3" too, in DEFAULT section)*

```
Define BAR__v1_0_0 "OK"

# CONDITIONAL
<IfDefine BAR__v1_0_0 >
    Define FOO "/bar/foo/bar_v1.0.0"
    Define BAR2 "foofoo1"
</IfDefine>
<IfDefine BAR__v2_0_0 >
    Define FOO "/bar/foo/bar_v2.0.0"
    Define BAR2 "foofoo2"
</IfDefine>

# DEFAULT
<IfDefine !FOO>
    Define FOO "/bar/foo/bar_v1.0.0"
    Define BAR2 "foofoo1"
</IfDefine>
```

Still, I was curious about this matter, especially what [@airtower-luna said on github](https://github.community/t/how-to-use-conditional-expressions-if-elseif-else-in-apache-with-custom-variables/251799/5). So I did another super-simple test:

```
<If "'word' == 'word'">
    Define BAR2 "foofoo1"
</If>
<ElseIf "'noword' == 'word'">
    Define BAR2 "foofoo2"
</ElseIf>
<Else>
    Define BAR2 "foofoo3"
</Else>
```

I did this too `<If "word == word">`

What is the result? The same !!! And I think this is ridiculous! I understand that `config` file it's not a script, but Apache guys made `IfDefine` work at startup, but not a simple-well-known for any coder `If` `Else`... I don't know what to say, only - well, ok then *(I’m not saying that with meaning/intention to disrespect someone)*. So, maybe I'll try someday the [@mike-kaminski solution](https://github.community/t/how-to-use-conditional-expressions-if-elseif-else-in-apache-with-custom-variables/251799/7), but not today. After all attempts I just really doubt it works at startup at all, as was [[said here]](https://github.community/t/how-to-use-conditional-expressions-if-elseif-else-in-apache-with-custom-variables/251799/5)